# $R_\xi$ gauges and the EM-field

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, gauge-theory, path-integral, gauge

$R_\xi$-gauges are said to be a generalization of the Lorenz gauge. I dont quite get why we add the term
$$
 \mathcal L_{GF} = - \frac{(\partial_\mu A ^\mu)^2}{2\xi}\tag{1}
$$
to the Lagrangian. If i calculate the EOM for the electromagnetic field $A^\mu$ adding the "gauge-breaking"-term (1) so for the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal L = - \frac 1 4 F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + j_\mu A^\mu - \frac{(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2}{2\xi}\tag{2}
$$
i get EOM
$$
\partial_{\nu}(\partial^\mu A^\nu + \left(\frac 1 \xi - 1\right)\partial^\nu A^\mu) = j^\mu\tag{3}
$$
which for $\xi = 1$ just gives the Lorenz gauge. Why is the $\xi = 1$ gauge now called Feynman-'t Hooft gauge? And what exactly is the use of this extra term since there is no "real" use for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Lagrangian of the path integral, a popular class of gauge-fixing terms is of the form$^1$
$${\cal L}_{GF}~=~-\frac{\chi^2}{2\xi}.$$
The word ["gauge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing) is here confusingly used in 2 ways:

1. The gauge-fixing function $\chi$, e.g. Lorenz gauge $\chi=\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}$, Coulomb gauge $\chi=\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{A}$, etc.
2. The [gauge parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing#R%CE%BE_gauges) $\xi>0$, e.g. Feynman – 't Hooft gauge $\xi=1$, Landau gauge $\xi=0^+$, etc.

Both gauge-fixing choices $(\chi,\xi)$ should be made. So e.g. OP is properly speaking considering Lorenz gauge $\chi=\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}$ in Feynman – 't Hooft gauge $\xi=1$.

Different gauges are useful in answering different questions. It should be stressed that the gauge-fixing condition is in generical only imposed in a quantum average sense in the path integral, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/540948/2451) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/24769/2451).

Why the path integral needs gauge-fixing is e.g. discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/306149/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173360/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130368/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139475/2451) Phys.SE posts.

--

$^1$ Some gauges may require non-trivial [Faddeev-Popov (FP) terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost). For a BRST formulation, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75981/2451) Phys.SE post. More general types of gauge-fixing is possible in the [Batalin-Vilkovisky (BV) formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalin%E2%80%93Vilkovisky_formalism).